# Problem with Spark DataType Equality for Spark Built in types

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While running a spark application i am getting errors deep inside catalyst.

For example:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.MatchError: LongType (of class org.apache.spark.sql.types.LongType$)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$Cast$$nullSafeCastFunction(Cast.scala:637)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.doGenCode(Cast.scala:625)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:107)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:104)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.genCode(Expression.scala:104)
```

I have narrowed this down to the following inside the spark plan:

```
Project [if (isnull(_rawTime#348L)) null else UDF(toTime(_rawTime#348L)) AS _time#438,
```

(note that i cannot control the schema being null, as i get this underlying dataframe from the spark hbase connector )

Where `toTime` is a UDF taking a long and producing a TimeStamp. It seems that catalyst is unable to match `LongType` even though the match statement has:

```
 case LongType => castToLongCode(from, ctx)
```

The interesting thing is that when i run this the first time it works fine. On the second run it has this problem.

Note this is being run via apache Livy so the underlying spark session should be the same between executions.

I placed the following code at the start of my job.

```
  logger.info("----------")
  logger.info(LongType + " " + System.identityHashCode(LongType))
  logger.info(DataTypes.LongType + " " + System.identityHashCode(DataTypes.LongType))
  logger.info("Equal " + (DataTypes.LongType == LongType))
  logger.info("----------")
```

And then running it i see:

```
first run:
----------
LongType 1044985410
LongType 1044985410
Equal true
----------
second run:
----------
LongType 355475697
LongType 1044985410
Equal false
----------
```

You can see on run 2, the Object based call to LongType is not the same identity as it was first run.

Spark's comment suggest people use the singletons that are in DataTypes.  Eg.. `DataTypes.LongType` which makes sense as it appears they stay the same. However, spark's own code uses the non-singleton.

LongType is defined as

```
/**
 * @since 1.3.0
 */
@InterfaceStability.Stable
case object LongType extends LongType
```

While `DataTypes.LongType` is

```
public static final DataType LongType = LongType$.MODULE$;
```

Which refers to the former (case object). It makes sense that the singleton will remain constant. In fact the spark code says `Please use the singleton`DataTypes.LongType`.` .. despite the fact that loads of internal spark code does not do this.  To me this feels like a bug.

It seems very odd that Scala code in Spark will compile fine then fail with this sudden identity change on the types.

So my questions are:

- What is the recommendation for using `DataType` in Spark? Should i use the singletons or the non-singletons?
- What might cause this identity to change underneath me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out the issue.

Basically all the DataType instances are defined in Scala as:

```
 * @since 1.3.0
 */
@InterfaceStability.Stable
case object LongType extends LongType
```

But ...in many places Spark uses java code which gets the DataTypes using singletons:

```
 * Gets the LongType object.
 */
public static final DataType LongType = LongType$.MODULE$;
```

The `LongType$.MODULE$;` is how to call a case object from java land.

But I was serializing a `DataType` to Livy using Kryo, and Kryo is internally re-initialising  `LongType$.MODULE$;`.   In Scala,  the reference you get when you get a case Object is tied not to the first instance created, but to the **last** instance created.

So the timeline is:

- time 0: `DataTypes.LongType` had a ref of 1,   `LongType` has ref of
  1 also. (where `ref` is just indicative of a reference )
- time 1: Kryo deserialises, and so reinstantiates the object. However the singleton DataTypes.LongType is pointing to the first instance. ie  `DataTypes.LongType` had a ref of 1,   `LongType` has ref of 2
- time >=2:  Chaos ensues - DataTypes wont pass equality checks.

The solution is not to pass case Objects to Kryo this way. It may be for some reason we aren't using Kryo correctly, or we need to use twitter/chill.